# How to open main page in PWA?

Tags: javascript, jquery, progressive-web-apps

I created PWA (Progressive Web Application). If user clicks on push notification, it opens at special page:

```
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function (event) {
    event.notification.close();
    clients.openWindow("...");
});
```

If user uses browser and clicks on button, this code works to go on main page:

```
window.location.replace('/');
```

But if user uses PWA, this code doesn't work. How can I go to the main page in PWA?